# How to insert records from one table to another using trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert the data from one table to another. The condition is if the first table having only record then only that record I need to insert into the another table.

I am trying Query :

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Map_Address(CustomerID, AddressID, IsBillingAddress)
SELECT [CustomerID], [ID], CAST('FALSE' as BIT) AS IsBillingAddress 
FROM CustomerAddress Group By CustomerID, ID
having COUNT(CustomerID) = 1
```

It is Grouped by CustomerID and ID hence getting wrong output. I want to group only by CustomerID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer_Map_Address (CustomerID, AddressID, IsBillingAddress)
SELECT [CustomerID], MAX([Id]), 0 AS IsBillingAddress
FROM dbo.CustomerAddress
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Don't you think it'll be better if you use COUNT(1) = 1 in having?

Comment: No. `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(1)`, `COUNT(PK_COLUMN)` generate equal execution plans